# Form to create relationship between objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my app I have `User` and `Language` models.
User can have multiple languages and a language can have multiple users.

```rb
class Language < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :languages
end
```

I want to create a form that will allow user to add a new language to the profile.
Since both `User` and `Language` models already exist, I'm wondering how to create a form that will not create any new model, but just create a relation between existing models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the has_many and HABTM macros create `_ids` and `_ids=` setters and getters that make it trivial to associate different records:

```
<%= form_with(model: @user) do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :language_ids, "Languages" %>
    <%= form.collection_select(:language_ids, Language.all, :id, :name, multiple: true) %>  
    # or if you prefer checkboxes 
    <%= form.collection_checkboxes(:language_ids, Language.all, :id, :name) %>   
  </div>

  # ...
<% end %>
```

The form collection helpers are smart enough to iterate accross the collection and will select/check depending on if an assocation already exists.

You whitelist an array parameter by passing a hash key to `permit` with an empty array as its value:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    # ...
  end


  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user)
          .permit(
            :foo, :bar, :baz,
            langauge_ids: []
          )
  end
end
```

I would also seriously consider if you want to use `has_and_belongs_to_many` in the first place. Since there is no model you can't access any additional columns on the join table like for example how proficient a user is or if its their primary language. There is also no straight forward way to query the join table directly. [`has_many through:`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) is a actually better solution in most cases.

Comment: Thanks, for the anwser. I'll consider if I really want to use `has_and_belongs_to_many` instead of `has_many through`.

Comment: I decided to use `has_many through`, but still one thing confuses me. Which method in which controller should be responsible for creating a new relation between existing user and language (user can add a language to the profile after sign in). Should it be `create` action in `UserLanguageController` (`UserLanguage` table joins `User` and `Language`)?

Comment: There is no simple answer to that one. It depends entirely on your use case and the desired user flow. One thing to bear in mind though is that your controller naming and endpoints should be designed off the RESTful api you want to expose or the user story. Your models are an internal implementation detail. Is a user langage an entity in its own right in your buisness domain that needs to be CRUDed on its own? In that case a separate controller makes sense. Not so much if its simply an attribute of user.